# Transparent switch from Wifi to ethernet

Tags: ip, wifi, failover, connection, ethernet

I have the following network setup:

- Zyxel USG 200 Firewall which also acts as DHCP server
- 2 Switches
- 2 Wifi APs (Zyxel NWA3560-N and WAC6503D-S) with NAT and DHCP disabled

The clients (mostly MacBooks) are normally connected to the switches by cable. The problem is that if you have to leave the workplace (e.g. go to a meeting room) and disconnect the ethernet cable, the connection breaks. So file transfers stop, SAPGUI closes the connection and with it all open windows, database connections and VPNs are interrupted etc.

I would like to avoid this. So when disconnecting or connecting the ethernet cable, programs should not notice the change.

I found a way to do this: assign the same IP address to both the ethernet and the wifi connection. Problems:

- It does not feel like a good thing to do.
- The DHCP server does not allow to assign the same IP to two different MAC addresses. So I have to enter them manually on the client. As we are often visiting clients, it is cumbersome to always change the IP settings.

Is there any "best practice" way of setting up such a scenario? I was thinking about setting up a tunnel or bridging the interfaces, but there probably is a much better way for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you are looking for is **bonding** see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_bonding). I'm not sure if macs have this. This [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083297/osx-link-aggregation-for-usb-tether-and-wifi) says no (in 2014) for wifi and ethernet, only for ethernet and ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the same IP address to the wireless and ethernet will NOT work (and may break things).

A tunnel is your best bet. There's no native OS or 802.1/802.11 support for this sort of thing. Industry is working on seamless multi-mode roaming but it is not possible on stock networking stacks today:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_TCP

There are some commercial solutions that do what you want:

https://columbitech.com/knowledge-center/seamless-roaming/

But if you want to do it on the cheap, simply setting up a UDP based OpenVPN configured with security loosened to allow client IP changes without reaunthenticating should do the trick.